# How to see voltage wave in simulink/simscape?

Tags: matlab, simulink, simscape

I'm analyzing the bahaviour of a RLC circuit and I need to observe the voltage and current wave of the circuit but I cannot find a way to do this. I need something like an oscilloscope but the *scope* does not work with the elements i am working with. What can I do?

The link below is my circuit, I'm using Simscape/Foundation Library elements

[This is my circuit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7NUQL.png)

Comment: Maybe try using a `sink` element to export the data to the MATLAB workspace and plotting the data using a MATLAB script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simscape and Simulink has different domains. To be able to use each one in the other domain, you need to use Simulink-PS Converter or PS-Simulink converter.

In that example, you have voltage sensor in Simscape and Scope or display in Simulink. To be able to connect them use PS-Simulink Converter.